# Xamarin when app going online to offine still parsing in queue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Unhandled Exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'result.resourceJobs[5].job.additionalFields.purchaseOrderNumber', line 1, position 5522. occurred

Comment: Well it sounds like you're parsing incomplete or invalid JSON. Unfortunately you haven't provided either your code or the data, so we can't say anything beyond that. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Exactly this issue occurring because I am handling exception wrong way   likes try{}catch(JsonSerializationException e){} but need to replace likes try{}catch(Exception e){}. now working fine for me..

Comment: No, you don't need to catch just `Exception` - you'd need to catch `JsonReaderException` or `JsonException`. I suggest you delete this question or improve it - in its current form it won't be useful to anyone else.